# Why am I getting such widely ranging values from this TMP36 in this circuit?

Tags: voltage-regulator, noise, temperature

**Background**

I have the following circuit built on a breadboard at this time.

I'm powering it off computer USB and a 5 V, 2 A wall wart (via USB) into the Nano Every (which is located on the breadboard -- making the ATMega4809 available).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqhytf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Reading temperature values**

I'm reading temperature values from the TMP36 and writing them to an SD Card along with times and displaying them on the OLED screen.

**Temperature values vary wildly**

I'm using the following library to read temperatures ==> https://github.com/Isaacr100/TMP36

This is a good library and basically wraps up the simple functionality of converting voltage to temperature.

The `getValues` function is basically everything you need to know about.

```
void TMP36::getValues() {
  _value = analogRead(_pin);
  _voltage = (_value/1024.0) * _aref;
  _tempC = (_voltage - .5) * 100;  
  _tempF = (_tempC * 1.8) + 32; 
}
```

**Main question**

Why do my temperature values vary so wildly from one reading to the next (70.4°F up to 74.44°F)?

### What I have tried

**1**. I **built an entire test board** which has 2 TMP36 components and a regular Arduino Nano (uses ATMega328). This board reads from two components on different Nano pins and writes the values to SD card so I can see how much they change -- also displays on an OLED.

**Results -- are different**

On this separate board, I see values that are much more in line with the actual room temperature (69 - 70°F) and they do not vary much at all -- within 0.5 - 1 degree of each other, but much of the time they are the same value.

**2**. I read the TMP36 datasheet and added 22 μF caps on the VCC / GND pins of all the TMP36 as they suggested and thought that would get better (for noise).  This didn't help in my circuit that is shown.

**3**. Because this calculates temperature from voltage I decided it was important to insure that my voltage was very precise. I installed a 3.3 V voltage regular and checked with multimeter.

**3.3V voltage regulator**

Notice that I'm insuring that my reference voltage is good also, by running a 3.3 V regulator into AREF on the Nano Every and using `analogReference(EXTERNAL)`.
This should insure that the temperature conversion is done in relation to a proper reference voltage.

I read the value off the regulator and I'm getting a solid 3.29 to 3.30 V.

I'm also passing thd proper voltage (3.29 V) into the TMP36 library (mentioned above).

**Circuit shown varies -- other board doesn't**

Since the test board has two TMP36 components on it, I've taken one out and swapped it with the one in the circuit shown  but it varies wildy only in the circuit shown, but not the test board.

**Why might this be?**

What types of things should I look at now?  Is this just because I have a lot of noise in this circuit?

**NOTE**: The two momentary buttons are wired properly for debounce but shown in the schematic as direct connect for simplicity.

Comment: 1) The [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/TMP35_36_37.pdf) seems to suggest only using a 0.1uF ceramic cap for C1. 2) Standard troubleshooting advice -- simplify your system. Determine the smallest circuit which doesn't work.

Comment: @ErikR Thanks for noticing the cap size and mentioning.  I'll look at that again and will also look at simplifying until it works properly.    I updated the schematic.  I have a 104 cap (.1uF) in the actual circuit - confirmed - had it wrong on schematic.

Comment: You shouldn't really have that much noise since you're not doing anything heavy, unless your bluetooth IC is taking a lot of current and your power supply cant source it. Are you seeing this variation on the screen? Or only noticing it on the SD card?

Comment: @BeB00 I'm seeing it in both places -- it seems the actual value I read varies and is higher both on the screen and written to the SD card.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: My test board is running right along side my shown circuit in this post and right now the test board is reading 72.60, 72.96 and the circuit is reading 75.01.

Comment: Do you have outputs turning on and off at the same time/comms other than serial running?  Some Arduino boards can have shameful amounts of ground bounce.

Comment: Did you put a scope on the output of the TMP36? What does the waveform look like?

Comment: @Hilmar I haven't put a scope on it, but you reminded me that I do actually have one and I will try it and see. I'll compare what I get from the main circuit to my test board TMP36s also.  Thanks very much.  I may post the additional info back here  -- because I may not understand what I see.  :)

Comment: @vir Thanks for mentioning that.  I'm wondering if displaying on OLED (via I2C) or writing to SD Card (via SPI) could be cause the problem.  Of course I am doing those two things on the test board too. I guess it could be the real-time clock causing the issue.  I'll try disconnecting the clock and seeing what happens too.  Thanks

Comment: @raddevus:  You have 5V going into your board from a wallwart, and you haveground from the PC.  There's a chance you have a ground loop causing problems.  Can you try powering the breadboard setup from the PC USB connection?  That would eliminate any possibility of a ground loop.

Comment: @JRE Thanks very much. Another of the tests that I have done is 1) run the test board from wall wart and main circuit from computer USB 2) swap the power supplies on both.  I will try it again and watch the data more closely.  Thank you for mentioning the possibility of a ground loop; provides me with another thing to examine.  

Comment: The data types used in the calculations can also cause such jumps; if they round/truncate. Have you observed the _value itself , does it jump around, as well?

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/Joe0x7F/TMP36

The TMP36 is a terribly unstable device. Try a MCP9701A or a LMT87.

Comment: How come my TMP236s read stable to roughly ~10 mK then ? This is nonsense.. The TMP236 and MCP9701 are obvious clones..

Comment: > "How come my TMP236s read stable to roughly ~10 mK then ?" - 

TMP236 != TMP36.

> "This is nonsense." - 

Nope. That's not what the data says.

> "The TMP236 and MCP9701 are obvious clones.." - 

Obviously, the MCP9701A and the LMT87 are NOT clones of the TMP36.

Comment: Ok these parts differ in some gain/offset values internally. They all share the same topology. I don't believe that - if properly connected and not broken - any part of that bunch will be magically 100x noisier than any other one.

Comment: It was hard for me to accept the reality I was looking at too.